# How To Get Discord.Net Bot To Join A Channel?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am making a Discord.Net bot and am struggling with coding it so it can join a specified channel. I have the Channel Id but I don't know to to get my bot to connect to the channel.

Comment: Google "Discord Developer Portal" if you haven't been there yet. Makes the process easy going that route, if I remember correctly it's just a few copy/pastes of generated tokens and choosing the channels you want to add it to.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if I ask dumb questions I'm 14 and new to programming.

Comment: No worries! I hope my comment was helpful.